# how to getElementById from all php texts id?

Tags: javascript, php, html, getelementbyid

php+js. I want to getElementById all texts id, but the result is only I can get the last id. I don't know how to deal with it...

html:

```
<div class="col-md-3 py-5">
    <button type="button" class="btn bg-light border rounded-circle" onclick="minus()"><i class="fas fa fa-minus" ></i></button>
    <input type="text" id="<?php echo $pro_id?>" value="<?php echo $pro_quantity?>" class="form-control w-25 d-inline">
    <button type="button" class="btn bg-light border rounded-circle" onclick="plus()"> <i class="fas fa fa-plus" ></i></button>
</div>
```

js:

```
<script>
    let count = 1;
    let countEl = document.getElementById("<?php echo $pro_id;?>");
    function plus(){
        count++;
        countEl.value = count;
    }
    function minus(){
        if (count > 1) count--;
        countEl.value = count;s
    }
</script>
```

Chrome js photo:

[image: Chrome js photo]

Comment: `getElementById` is get only the first `id` you can use instead `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: There should only ever be _one_ element on the page with an ID. IDs _are unique_. Use a class instead.

Comment: I suspect there's more happening here than you're sharing.  The JavaScript code you're showing should not produce the output in your screen shot, because (1) there's no reason JavaScript would expand the `$s` variable in that string literal and (2) even if it did, that's not the value of that variable and (3) expanding the value would happen at runtime, not in the actual visible source code.  So where is that `"19"` coming from?  What is the `id` of the element you're targeting?  Can you clarify the problem and provide a more complete example?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the id to get the elements, try using a different selector.

```
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');

inputs.forEach((input) => {
  // Do stuff
  console.log(input.value);
});
```

Note, this will select all text inputs on the page so consider adding a more specific selector if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

We can use only one id for one page.

Use class instead of id.

Or if possible pass your current id in plus(id) function and minus(id) function

Answer (score -1):

using jquery:

```
$('div button i.fa-minus').parent().click(function(){
    let last_value = $(this).parent().children("input").val();
    last_value++;
    $(this).parent().children("input").val(last_value);
});
$('div button i.fa-plus').parent().click(function(){
    let last_value = $(this).parent().children("input").val();
    if(last_value <= 1) return;
    last_value--;
    $(this).parent().children("input").val(last_value);
});
```